# Selenium WebDriverException missing ) after argument list

Tags: selenium

```
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('input[name='password']');");
```

This line is throwing the following Exception in thread:

> "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('input[name=\'password\']')");
```

Comment: No luck,still its not working. while //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']"‌​)).sendKeys("gamb"); is working fine .but js.executeScript("document.querySelector('input[name=\'pas‌​sword\']').value='ga‌​mb'"); is not working

Comment: you can try with document.querySelector('input[name=\'pas‌sword\']').setAttribute('value','gamb');

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('input[name='password']')");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: No luck,still its not working.    while //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']")).sendKeys("gamb"); is working fine .but   js.executeScript("document.querySelector('input[name=\'password\']').value='gamb'"); is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following

```
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\'input[name=\'password\']\');");
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"input[name='password']\");");
```

Although in your comments you added this line

```
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('input[name=\'pas‌​‌​sword\']').value='ga‌​‌​mb'");
```

Which wouldn't work because if you look at .value you'll need to escape your .value setting as well more than likely.

Given that I don't have access to your site or your code, I would suggest that you test to make sure your javascript is valid for your page. One way to do so would be to take the javascript itself (everything insdie the .executeScript) and run it through your browsers dev tools console or script execution window.

If the value sets using the browsers dev tools, great...issue is with selenium. If the value does not set using browser dev tools...you'll need to refactor your javascript as the problem is likely not with selenium, rather your JS selector more than likely.

Although, the following, from your comment, works...you may not need to execute it via javascript.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']"‌​‌​)).sendKeys("gamb"‌​);
```